# Grails HTTPClient Connection Reset Error

Tags: networking, grails, groovy, httpclient

I am using an HTTPClient object for posting to a resource that resides on another Server. The POST request performed by HTTPClient is done in a loop as I have multiple requests (in fact the number can be 10,000 or even more). After some time while the logic is sending requests the whole process breaks and "Connection reset" error is logged in the log file.

Any ideas as to why this might be happening? Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you getting and exception on either server?

Comment: Not getting any exception on either server except "Connection reset" error in the server that's sending request.

Comment: Can you add a delay and see if that does anything ? Also can you post the code

Comment: Could also be a local networking problem or the doing of the ISP

Answer (score -1):

I got this error too, but , mine is another way.

In your situration , perhaps is caused by "keep-alive"...Forgive me , I forget what this was called for, I just remembered it had two parameters:"keep-alive" and "closed".

Suggest you to check it in this point.

Hope this can help you ^_^